# How to update Layout in PortletLayoutListener

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

The goal is to implement a Tab Portlet - portlet for displaying and managing tabs containing nested portlets (similar to Nested Portlets Portlet).

One of the requirements is to remove the nested portlet references from Layout on Tab Portlet removal.

I implemented PortletLayoutListener and indeed, method onRemoveFromLayout is called on Tab Portlet removal. The listener updates the layout. While debugging the listener, I can verify that the changes were written to Liferay database (to LAYOUT table).
The Layout instance is obtained through LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(plid) method. 
The update is performed with LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout method.

The problem is that the listener is called from UpdateLayoutAction, which afterwards updates the Layout itsef and overwrites my changes (it reverts them).

The question is - is it possible to update Layout in PortletLayoutListener.onRemoveFromLayout method? If not, is there other option I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the PortletLayoutListeners are intended to be used in relation to the portlet. So if you want to react on a change on the page in your portlet.

If you want to change the portal, I would have a look at the model listeners. Create a hook with a Layout model listener and try to make you changes in the afterUpdate method. But be careful not to affect the performance.

You may even require both of the classes one to make an indication and the second one to make a change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to handle an event, where the portlet is removed from the layout and update the layout afterwards. `PortletLayoutListener` lets me handle this particular event, but the listener cannot update the layout. As of model listeners - the model listeners are not meant to update the model. Usually they listen to model changes and peform actions on different entities.